# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "options" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

allo. i get this error when i try to "heroku run rake db:migrate" :

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "options" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"options"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"options"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:768:in `async_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:768:in `exec_no_cache'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:138:in `block in exec_query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:425:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:420:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:137:in `exec_query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:915:in `column_definitions'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:174:in `columns'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:114:in `block in prepare_default_proc'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:56:in `yield'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:56:in `columns'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:208:in `columns'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:217:in `columns_hash'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:60:in `block in valid?'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:60:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:60:in `all?'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:60:in `valid?'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:18:in `method_missing'
/app/app/models/option.rb:4:in `get_config_value'
/app/app/models/achat.rb:17:in `<class:Achat>'
/app/app/models/achat.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:329:in `require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:288:in `depend_on'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:206:in `require_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `block in eager_load!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `eager_load!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:347:in `eager_load!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:249:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "options" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"options"'::regclass
                                          ^
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:768:in `async_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:768:in `exec_no_cache'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:138:in `block in exec_query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:425:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:420:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:137:in `exec_query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:915:in `column_definitions'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:174:in `columns'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:114:in `block in prepare_default_proc'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:56:in `yield'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:56:in `columns'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:208:in `columns'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:217:in `columns_hash'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:60:in `block in valid?'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:60:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:60:in `all?'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:60:in `valid?'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:18:in `method_missing'
/app/app/models/option.rb:4:in `get_config_value'
/app/app/models/achat.rb:17:in `<class:Achat>'
/app/app/models/achat.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:329:in `require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:288:in `depend_on'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:206:in `require_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `block in eager_load!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `eager_load!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:347:in `eager_load!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:249:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
'
```

but when i run "rake db:migrate" on my computer it run fine. can anybody help me please. i work with rails 4.0.0, ruby 2.2.3, Postgres SGBD and i'm in linuxmint 17

my migration :

```
class CreateOptions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :options do |t|
      t.string :config_key
      t.string :config_value

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

my model :

```
class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
   class << self
   def get_config_value(key)
      c = find_by_config_key(key)
      c.nil? ? nil : c.config_value
    end


    def set_config_values(values_hash)
      values_hash.each_pair { |key, value| set_value(key.to_s.camelize, value) }
    end

    def set_value(key, value)
      config = find_by_config_key(key)
      config.nil? ?
        Option.create(:config_key => key, :config_value => value) :
        config.update_attribute(:config_value, value)
    end

    def get_multiple_configs_as_hash(keys)
      conf_hash = {}
      keys.each { |k| conf_hash[k.underscore.to_sym] = get_config_value(k) }
      conf_hash
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: Do you have a table named "options" in the database? can you connect to your PG instance in order to verify? If so, do you have a model named "options" in your rails app?

Comment: Can you add the code for migration that raises the error?

Comment: You have `class Option < ActiveRecord::Base` and you're using that class in your migration or your applications initialization code. But you can't use `Option` until your migrations run to create it and you can't run your migrations until your application starts up but you can't do that until `Option` is ready but you can't do that until you migrate but ...

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. In effect heroku first checks the model before setting up the database and at the level of my class options i created a subclass that inherited options that's where the error came from. I first removed this heritage, executed the migrate, and then restored it and walked it. thank you